# Set the google map fragment and the linearlayout programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `linearLayout` as described below in `map.xml`. In it there's a `fragment`, `view`, and `linearLayout "map_below"`. Is it possible to implement the `fragment`, `view` and `linearLayout` so that the height of the `fragment` and `linearLayout
"map_below"` will be configured programmatically? The `map_below linearLayout` contains a `Text View` for the title of all markers to let the user know which markers are displayed in the Google map.

I think the problem is that the map must be displayed to set the markers in it, and also that the map height must be defined. Consequently, the `map_below linearLayout` gets the rest of the screen height. Currently I'm facing a problem to display all titles in the `map_below` since the `fragment` has a limited height of `500dp`. Can I set the height of the `fragment` as well as the `map_below` programmatically?

**map.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#181407"/>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/map_below"    
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#303230"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: AFAIK you can set it programmatically too

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tendp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" >

                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </fragment>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_getdirection"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/map"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fivedp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:src="@drawable/mapdirection" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_dictance"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fivedp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_getdirection"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#616161" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_direction"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fivedp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_getdirection"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center|left"`enter code here`
                        android:text="Direction"
                        android:textColor="#616161" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```